# Compiling Programs from Within Emacs?

Tags: c, emacs, compilation, clang, eshell

What is the best way to compile programs inside emacs? I am currently opening a separate buffer with `C-x 3` and running eshell inside it using `M-x eshell` then invoking either make or clang directly; most of the time I do have a Makefile set up.

Is there any advantage with running the compilation process using `M-x compile` vs running make inside eshell? Any other ways to do it and what are the advantages/disadvantages of those?

Comment: Not familiar with eshell, but I'm pretty sure it won't support C-x `

Comment: @carlosdc eshell is the built in UNIX shell inside emacs written in lisp. It behaves like any standard UNIX shell but within emacs. I just open it in a separate buffer within emacs.

Comment: yes, it seems like you're missing out on a lot of emacs functionality. Will's answer explains the features of M-x compile nicely.

Comment: I'd _definitely_ go with `M-x compile`, having just tried `make` inside `M-x eshell`. In fact, `M-x compile` is one of the few keybindings I regularly use (`C-x c` if you're interested).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the Emacs built-in `compile` command. `M-x compile` should do you fine. You can then edit the command that will be run (by default `make -k`) and then hit return to run the compilation. Emacs will then parse the output and if it finds any errors they will link to the source files so you can open them in a buffer.

Positives about it are:

- Parsing of the output buffer
- Memorisation of the compile command between invocations
- Compilation output is shown in a non-selected buffer, you can quickly edit the file you were working on and fix any silly errors.
- `M-n` and `M-p` scroll by *error messages*

Most of these features are provided by the `compilation-minor-mode` minor mode though not the actual compilation command and buffer. Once you have run a compilation command in `eshell` you could probably get similar results by setting the minor mode to `compilation-minor-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to run `make` or whatever command you're using to
compile within a [multi-term](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm)
for the following reasons:

- it works like <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile`<kbd>RET</kbd> if you activate
  `compilation-shell-minor-mode` (<kbd>M-p</kbd>, <kbd>C-`</kbd>, …).
- but you can, obviously, use other commands like

  ```
  mkdir build
  cd build
  ./configure --with-another-option
  ```

  Of course you can do this from Emacs but I prefer the shell
  interaction for this kind of stuff.

And imo, the main drawback of <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile` is that if
you're editing a file located in another directory than your
`Makefile` then you have to use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile` in the correct
directory and then <kbd>M-x</kbd>`recompile`. But if you want, say to
`make clean && make`, then you'll have to switch to the correct
directory, do it, switch back.

However `term.el` has its own drawback, it uses a non-portable hacky
way to track the current directory.